# either a rookie mistake, or misuse of .equals in java

Tags: java, string, boolean

So I'm making a TicTacToe-program, and I made a method for checking if there are 3 pieces in a row, to check if the game is over or not.

```
public boolean hasWon() {
    if (tictac[0][0].equals(tictac[1][0]) && tictac[0][0].equals(tictac[2][0]) && tictac[1][0].equals(tictac[2][0])) { //Vertical
        return false;
    } else if (tictac[0][1].equals(tictac[1][1]) && tictac[0][1].equals(tictac[2][1]) && tictac[1][1].equals(tictac[2][1])) { //Vertical
        return false;
    } else if (tictac[0][2].equals(tictac[1][2]) && tictac[0][2].equals(tictac[2][2]) && tictac[1][2].equals(tictac[2][2])) { //Vertical
        return false;

    } else if (tictac[0][0].equals(tictac[0][1]) && tictac[0][0].equals(tictac[0][2]) && tictac[0][1].equals(tictac[0][2])) { //Horizontal
        return false;
    } else if (tictac[1][0].equals(tictac[1][1]) && tictac[1][0].equals(tictac[1][2]) && tictac[1][1].equals(tictac[1][2])) { //Horizontal
        return false;
    } else if (tictac[2][0].equals(tictac[2][1]) && tictac[2][0].equals(tictac[2][2]) && tictac[2][1].equals(tictac[2][2])) { //Horizontal
        return false;

    } else if (tictac[0][0].equals(tictac[1][1]) && tictac[0][0].equals(tictac[2][2]) && tictac[1][1].equals(tictac[2][2])) { //Diagonal
        return false;
    } else if (tictac[0][2].equals(tictac[1][1]) && tictac[0][2].equals(tictac[2][0]) && tictac[1][1].equals(tictac[2][0])) { //Diagonal
        return false;

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem here is, with these conditions I figured if, say, all of the indexes "in a row" where f.ex. X, " X X X " it would be a win for the player X. However, my program calls for a winner if any kind of piece fill 3 in a row, f.ex. " X O X " would end the game, which obviously is wrong. 
Have I misunderstood .equals?

EDIT: after the wonderful feedback, is there a way that I can make the if-statements to ignore blank spaces ("   ")?

Comment: show us the declaration of your `equals` method

Comment: show us the declaration of `tictac`.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but if you're comparing three things and you find that A equals B, and A equals C, then you don't need to check that B equals C.  This is because equality is _transitive_.

Comment: private String[][] tictac = new String[3][3]; is this the right one?

Comment: The problem may be that you're returning `false` when three things in a row are equal, and `true` if they're not.  Isn't that kind of backwards?  Another issue: What is the value of `tictac[i][j]` if the square is empty?  You don't want it returning `Win` if there are three blank squares in a row!!

Comment: You haven't misunderstood `equals`, but you've misunderstood `false` and `true`.  Look carefully at what you're returning.

Comment: Indeed it is backwards, but it "has to be" for the loop in another class to work properly. As for the three blank spaces, I added a condition so that the hasWon won't be called before the 5th round. But still, the "empty" squares are "   ", 3 spaces. I tried !tictac.equals("   "), but it didn't work.

Comment: nope, not unless your code "has to" run incorrectly.

Comment: Since you'll be calling `hasWon` after each turn, one option would be to pass in the value (`"X"` or `"O"`) that you want to check for; then in each `if` condition, just check whether all three squares have the value that you've passed in.  Another option would be to pass in the co-ordinates of the square that was just filled, and check only the lines that include that square - that way, you know you won't pick up the "three blanks in a row" case.

Comment: @Mark if `hasWon` needs to return the backwards result, then the name should be changed to `hasNotWon`, perhaps.  This kind of trickery is how nasty bugs get into software (real production software, not just homework assignments).  But it shouldn't "have to" return the wrong result; you can always add a `!` to the code that calls it in the other loop.

Comment: Anyway, given that `hasWon` is supposed to return `false` if somebody has won, then I don't really see why your code wouldn't work.  You haven't misunderstood `.equals`.  Maybe the code that sets up the array is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider creating a class, `Board`. Have this class provide an interface that includes `getLines`. This should return a `List<Line>`. There are eight lines in a tic tac toe board: three horizontal, three vertical, two diagonal. Create a method `isWin(String player, Line line)`. Return true or false based on whether the count of the player's marker in the cells of the line is three.

I would guess you can write the whole thing in the same amount of space as the horrible nested `if` with all its inscrutable `&&` clauses, and the functioning will be obvious.  (This is also good practice for encapsulation.)

Answer (score 0):

Your prog returns true if all three values on some line are the same. So, it won't return true on XOX. But would on OOO, XXX and SpaceSpaceSpace.

The first two are both OK, for if you check after a move, only the last mover could have three in a line and win. But three spaces are a problem. In every if you should check the first cell for not having space.

It is longer, but if you use the advice of @ajb, you'll even shorten the prog.

As for structuring, I would advice more simple way than that of @syrion. Make an array lines[5,3,2]. It has 5 lines, 3 cells for every line and 2 coords for every cell. And you can do the check in two inserted loops. It is not a Java way to do things, but you can take it as a first step. Or you could move immediately to a more readable structure - a list of 5 x lines= array of Cell = pair of coordinates. I don't know which one is more simple for you.